# How to vertically maximize windows in Elementary OS?

Tags: window-management

How can I stretch windows vertically so that they fill the entire available height of the screen?

Maximizing a window fills up the total desktop space which I don't want. If the window is maximized I have to move my eyes across the entire width of the screen and jumping to the next line is difficult because one has to track their eyes along the same line backwards to find the start of the next line.

I just want the browser to fill up the maximum vertical space. It is easier to read and I find myself doing it way often so I figured why not automate this.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you drag the window to the left or right of the screen, it will "snap" to that side, taking up the full vertical space and half the horizontal space. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to "snap" the active window to one side or the other.

Comment: That sort of gets the job done, but that doesn't let me put more than two windows vertically expanded on the screen. Further as soon as you try to move the vertically expanded window to the centre, it collapses to its previous dimensions.

Comment: I think I might've misunderstood your original question. What are you looking to do? Are you looking to make a single window take up the full height of the screen without moving it or changing its width, and without having to drag it?

Comment: Yes, that is right.